# Find file while other file exist in same directory

Tags: linux, bash, find, for

I'm trying to do "one line script" or really small bash script.

It have to find file (for example `./xxx/one.php`) and if that file exist edit (with `printf` or `echo`) other file IN SAME directory (for example `./xxx/test.php`).

Right now I made second part - editing existing file, but I don't have idea how to, or where to enter "if".

Actually I have something like that

```bsh
for file in `find . -name "test*.php"` ; do

(printf "It's me, on first line \n and me on second line\n" && cat $file) > "$file".bak && mv "$file".bak "$file"

done
```

It's should be something like this?

```bsh
if [[ `find . -name "one*.php` ]]; do

for file in `find . -name "test*.php"` ; do

(printf "It's me, on first line \n and me on second line\n" && cat $file) > "$file".bak && mv "$file".bak "$file"

done
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-execdir` option to `find` is handy here:

```
find -name 'one*.php' -execdir bash -c '
if [ -e test.php ] ; then
    printf ... && mv test.bak test.php
fi' {} \;
```

[`-execdir` is](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find)

> Like `-exec`, but the specified command is run from the subdirectory containing the matched file, which is not normally the directory in which you started find.

`-execdir` will run the given command in the directory the found file was in, so the `test.php` file "next to" it will be right there to manipulate. Here we launch `bash` in that directory and run a small script there to make the manipulations you want. There's no need to complex path manipulations or re-finding the file. Above I check that the file exists, but if it will always be there (or you want to create it unconditionally) you can take the `if` out.

`-execdir` is a GNU find extension, not in POSIX, but you very likely have that given your tags. One caveat is that [your `PATH` environment variable can't contain `.` or any other relative paths](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Single-File.html#Single-File) (including an empty element), for security reasons, so if your ambient one does you'll need to reset it first: `PATH=... find ...`.

Comment: So because my PATH can't contain dot... it will by default search in current directory?

Comment: If you have a `.` or empty element in `PATH`, executables will be searched for in the current directory, but the *default* is that they are not. That part is just a caveat about when `find -execdir` will refuse to run, which is confusing to encounter otherwise.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you for explaining.

Comment: I found that when I pasted that into .sh executable file and run it I get
```bash
skrypt.sh: line 4: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
skrypt.sh: line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: You're missing a closing `"`, somewhere. I don't know where, because that's something you've added, but the opening quote should be on line 4.

Comment: ```bash
#!/bin/bash
find -name 'move.mo' -execdir bash -c '
if [ -e test.te ] ; then
(printf "It's me, on first line \n and me on second line\n" && cat test.te) > test.te.bak && mv test.te.bak test.te
fi' {} \;
```
I don't see where, all `"` exists

Comment: The apostrophe in `It's` closes the single quotes and needs to be escaped.

Comment: I've escaped with `\\` and same output

Comment: For single quotes, unfortunately, you have to do: `'"'"'` or `'\''` to escape a single quote inside them (i.e. end the quote, quote the quote outside, and re-enter single quotes) - backslashes aren't processed inside the `' ... '`.